# Automatic extension of strict convexity

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities

Let $\phi:\mathbb [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be convex, and **strictly** convex on $[a,\infty)$, for some  $a \in (0,\infty)$.

Let $x>a\ge y$, and suppose that
$$\phi(t x + (1-t) y) = t\phi(x) + (1-t)\phi(y).$$

How to prove that $t\in \{0,1\}$?

I am quite sure this should not be complicated, but I am not sure how to approach this.

**Edit:**

I think that this should follow from the following claim: If a convex function agrees with a chord at some interior point, then it must *coincide with this chord all the way*-i.e. be affine on the relevant segment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\phi$ is strictly convex only on $[a,\infty).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$ and $0\le x < y <z,$ then

$$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \le \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}.$$

When does equality hold?